# Finding the key respective values in bimap

Tags: boost

I have a bimap

```
boost::bimap<std::string, vector<string>> mymap;
```

I have to seach for the vector mapped to the exact key type 
i.e `std::string`. Getting some problem while printing the right part which exactly mapped to right string.

Something like below

```
auto it = mymap.left.find(input):
```

After finding the it I am able to print `it->first`;

I am facing problem in printing the second part i.e `vector<string>` which is exactly mapped to the `it->first`.

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure boost or bimap are relevant to this question. If you had `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> mymap; auto it = mymap.find(input);` wouldn't you have the exact same question?

Answer (score 2):

It's in `it->second`;

You'd print it in any way you normally would print the vector, e.g.

```
for(auto& el : it->second)
    std::cout << el << "\n";
```

Or

```
stc::copy(it->second.begin(),
     it->second.end(),
     std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```